# cannot use PySide2 qtwebengine on 32 bit

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, python-3.6, pyside2, qt5.6

Whenever I install PySide2 on my windows 32 bit system from

```
pip install --index-url=http://download.qt.io/snapshots/ci/pyside/5.11/latest/ pyside2 --trusted-host download.qt.io
```

I cannot find or even use the webenginewidgets module,
I have seen on many forums that PyQt5 on 32 bit systems doesnt ship with | support QtWebEngineWidgets

I have tried all installations including conda and winpython but no rescue

Comment: you may also look for help at https://gitter.im/PySide/pyside2

Comment: @AbhishekMathur see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62513